# How to Consume webservice using Ext js Ajax

Tags: ajax, web-services, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

Hi I am trying to access a Google map web service and the code snippet is

```
      Ext.Ajax.request({
                url:"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json",
                    method:"GET",
                    cors:true,
                params:{
                         location:"39.6034810,-119.6822510",
                         timestamp:"1331161200"
                       },
                success:function(response){
                       },
                failure:function(){
                        alert("failure");
                       }


            });
```

But when i start running it I am getting an error

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?_dc=1415326803777&location=39.6034810%2C-119.6822510&timestamp=1331161200. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

As said in the error description I have enabled the CORS in my ajax reqeust still I am facing these problem.

Kindly help me.

Comment: You can make use of jsonp for making cross domain calls take a look here http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [this link](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?267051-extjs4-Ext.Ajax.Request-and-Cross-domain&p=978374&viewfull=1#post978374) for CORS

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?267051-extjs4-Ext.Ajax.Request-and-Cross-domain&p=978374&viewfull=1#post978374